# Integrating SQL environment in my java project

Tags: java, sql, integration

I have a java project that is a question bank on SQL, I am adding a tester field where I want my tester to be able to execute the query on the database in the testing environment for that I want to integrate the SQL execution environment into my project. How can this be done and does it require me to buy a separate server any, inputs would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: **SQL** is a **query language** - not a database product or an "environment". Please add a relevant tag to clear up which **concrete RDBMS** you're talking about here - `oracle`, `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `db2` or whatever else it might be ....

Comment: Why not use JDBC instead of doing some strange integration?